# How to write sorting scope for netzke grid column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, netzke

When I am trying to implement sorting scope for one of my grid columns it always throws an error
as `NoMethodError (undefined method`to_sym' for #)`

My code is

```
{  
:name => :id,  
:text => "Title",     
:sorting_scope => lambda {|r| r.order("id desc") }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently `sorting_scope` for a column can only accept the name of a scope defined on the model directly, see example in the documentation: https://github.com/netzke/netzke-basepack/blob/master/lib/netzke/basepack/grid.rb#L150

Comment: Yes I checked and is working as expected. Thanks...!